# Concatenating rows based on key in pandas datafraem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe , I want to concat values based on key
for example,

```
c1      c2 c3  c4  c5
14206   3.5 0   0   0
14206   0   0   0   0
14206   0   0   0   0
14206   0   0   0   0
```

want it to be like ...

```
14206 3.5   0   0   0 0 0   0   0 0 0   0   0 0 0   0   0
```

I tried df.groupBy(id), but can't figure out what to do next

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. group by column 0, filter to keep only the data columns, then unstack them all and transpose them as you want a row and not a column:

```
df.groupby('c1')[['c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']].apply(lambda g: g.unstack().T)
Out[16]: 
        c2                  c3                  c4                  c5       \
         0    1    2    3    0    1    2    3    0    1    2    3    0    1   
c1                                                                            
14206  3.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   


         2    3  
c1               
14206  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: the result appearing as columns

Comment: edited with your columns, the answer stands the same